# set Target name in .vcxproj for visual studio 2017

Tags: xml, visual-studio, configuration

If I open a solution of projects, after build each project produces a `$(ProjectName).dll`. The project name is automatically set to whatever is before the `.vcxproj`.

For example if I have a project called `someName.vcxproj` then the produced output is `someName.dll`. How can I set the project name in the `.sln` or in the `.vcxproj` so that I set it to what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the *Target Name* of the output assembly in the project properties.

Just name your project whatever you like and adjust the *Target Name* under

```
Configuration Properties -> General -> Target Name
```

The changed *Target Name* is written to the .vcxproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
  <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  <TargetName>Foo</TargetName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

so it will be passed along with your project.

Comment: Since you mention git - have you considered simply creating a branch for VS 2017?

Comment: Thanks! it did change it.